# Adding Custom Manifest file with Docker image/tag

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

Like we can add our own custom manifest file in Jar files. is there a way to add Custom Manifest in Docker images/tags. Like If I want to add all the JIRA ids fixed in a release can I add those to manifest file for that tag

Thanks,
Amol

Answer (score 1):

Well, to Docker containers, you can add any arbitrary files with `ADD` or `COPY` commands.

So, you can write a script (a `bash` script, for example) that gets the `JIRA` ids, creates a manifest file (`JIRA-IDs.manifest`, for example). Then, in your build script, you'll generate this file and, in your Dockerfile, just add:

```
COPY JIRA-IDs.manifest /
```

If you'll need to process this manifest data, it's a good idea to create it in a "parser friendly" format, like `json`, `csv`, line separated, space separated, etc.

After doing this, you can get the contents of `JIRA-IDs.manifest` that's running inside the container using `docker exec`, for example.

Of course, if you're using a programming language / framework that allow you to do that, do it so. Otherwise, you can always "go by scratch", creating a manual file like that.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey @Amol, did this help you?